# How can I solve this issue "error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset"?

Tags: git, github

```
$ git push -u -f origin --all
Enumerating objects: 44, done.
Counting objects: 100% (44/44), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44/44), 213.97 KiB | 3.15 MiB/s, done.
Total 44 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
$ git push -u -f origin
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a server side problem. What can you see on the server side?

Comment: 408 is a request timeout. Maybe a proxy problem?